# Splitting Code into Different Classes [Bukkit/Spigot]

Tags: java, bukkit

So I created this small plugin and I want to know how to move the code from inside onCommand to another class and call/execute that class inside onCommand.
Please Help. Thanks

```
public class SkinStandoff extends JavaPlugin {
Block bEnd;
Location End;
Block ZeroBlock;
Location Zero;
Location ZeroEnd;

@Override
public void onEnable(){
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String args[]) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("build") && sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        Location start;
        int Count;
        Count = 1;

        start = player.getLocation();
        End = start.add(3, -1, 3);
        Zero = getEnd().add(1,0,0);

        bEnd = End.getBlock();
        bEnd.setType(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
        do {
            Zero= Zero.add(1,0,0);
            ZeroBlock = Zero.getBlock();
            ZeroBlock.setType(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
            Count++;
        } while (Count != 10);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public Location getEnd(){
    return End;
}
public Location getZeroEnd(Location ZeroEnd){
    ZeroEnd = this.Zero.add(10,0,0);
    return ZeroEnd;
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: learn about java naming conventions. I have no idea the libraries you are using; and I am really wondering if your Zero* variables should somehow be constants; or why they all start with UpperCase names!

Comment: And for the record: questions on improving working code might also go to codereview.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create new Class Commands and there will be:

```
public class Commands implements CommandExecutor {

    private MainClass plugin;

    public Commands(MainClass core) {
        this.plugin = core;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
your commands here
return true;
}
}
```

And in your MainClass you have to set CommandExecutor:

```
getCommand("command").setExecutor(new Commands(this));
```